# Startup problem on dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 - Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown

So I have a dual boot windows-linux system running on a Lenovo G50-80. There is only one hard-drive partition shared between both. Everything was running fine until I used ntfsfix on the shared drive.

Usually I have to do a complete windows shutdown(rather than a fast/hybrid shutdown) to get unhindered access to the shared partition on Ubuntu. If I forget doing that I use ntfsfix on the partition.

**Stuff that's annoying**:

- Every time I shutdown from windows and try to boot up on Ubuntu I get thrown into emergency mode with the following: **ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUNDNamespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND**
  **ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0.** ... Looks something like this [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig4_zNqonWAhWEuY8KHeH4DNcQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F737773%2Fcan-not-boot-ubuntu-into-default-mode&psig=AFQjCNEgO7IG6B5BiQh307Hasz_VYl00FA&ust=1504538954052898)
  I do not understand why this is happening. Also it might not end up with a static screen at all and would flicker showing the Ubuntu logo and this error screen in rapid succession.
- If I shutdown from Ubuntu I get a very loud beep with short ups and downs which I realise is something of an error code related to BIOS and hardware. This is fixed by using the power button to shut off the computer and trying to boot it up again. When it does with the Lenovo logo on screen, there's no beep sound.

Sometimes I have to boot into recovery mode in Ubuntu using the advanced options in GRUB. Other times I just have to restart my computer a couple of times to get it right. What could be causing this? Do I need to reinstall ubuntu? If yes how?

Comment: I have this error too on new installs of debian 9 as well, with regular SATA as with SATA SSD drives: 
"ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUNDNamespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [_SB_.PCI0..."
-------
But the machines  appear to have no other issues
-------
I mean: this error is probably unrelated to the problem you face.